# jQuery - Function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two .js files. On the first .js file i declare and execute a function like this:

```
(function($){
  function something(){
    //code here
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    something();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Also, I want to execute the something() function in the second .js. My code is the following:

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //more code
    something();
    //more code
  });
})(jQuery);
```

However, when the program is executed, I get the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: something is not defined(…)

**Possible Solution:**
I solved the problem declaring the function as:

```
(function($){
  this.something = function(){
    //code here
  }

})(jQuery);
```

Is this 100% right?

Comment: Can you show where exactly you have defined `one`? Looks like a scoping issue.

Comment: Please elaborate your question more...

Comment: It's a scope problem - move the definition of `something()` *outside* of the closure.

Comment: @downvoters: its not a reason to downvote just because somebody didnt understand the principle. the question is perfectly fine. you can vote to close and we all can move on, but that aggressive downvoting is not cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal, you declared your function `something` in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), so you can't using it outside your block. Try to declare your function outside `(function($) ...)()` block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that, but a new error occured: "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(…)". I read that when the function is executed like this: $("selector").function1(), then we declare it like this: $.fn.function1(){}. However, in my case, I just call the function without a selector. How should I declare it?

Comment: At the top of your file, before `$(function() ...)()`. But I think you are misunderstanding js scopes, you should have a look [here](https://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/). Btw, `$.fn.function1(){}` is a kind of jQuery function-plugin, it's not standard js, be careful

Answer (score 2):

You cant define a function inside a scope and try to use that function in another scope. You have not understood how functions and scopes work in JavaScript.

[Have a look at this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Comment: If you are voting to close, please don't answer. This should be technically a comment. ps: I didn't downvote.

Comment: I just tried to help you.

Comment: @Alex you are right but answering to wrong question :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar I know, I can handle it ;)

Comment: @Alex Sure.. :)

Comment: I know that we can't define a function inside an IIFE and then use it in another IIFE but if you look into this code https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/blob/master/jquery.lettering.js, you will see that when you call lettering() from another IIFE, it works fine. That's why I'm confused

Comment: @themis93 i still dont understand :) we should start a chat so maybe i can help you and explain a bit but this is really basic javascript

Comment: Ok. It would be very useful for me if you could explain me all these things that I haven't understand. However, I'm new here and I don't know how to start a chat :(

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129452/js-session